# Writing a javascript to display the denomination of the amount deposited

Tags: javascript

I absolutely have no idea on how to proceed with this, that is why I could not produce a SSCCE !

I would like to write a javascript that displays denomination of the amount deposited in the bank in terms of 100's, 50's, 20's, 10's, 5's, 2's & 1's.

For example: If I deposit Rs.163, the output should be 1-100's, 1-50's, 1-10's, 1-2's & 1-1's

Please help me with this...

Comment: Look into the mod function.. `%`

Comment: not something I was looking for ... As I said, I absolutely have no idea on starting this!

Comment: Kinda sounds like homework. Also, aren't there numerous ways to breakdown the original amount?

Comment: I had a seriously complex recursive script to give me the best breakdown on postage when I selected the stamps I had, then the post office changed to Postage 1 and Postage 2 :/

Comment: Subtract the largest coin as many times as you can then move on the the next coin.

Comment: I concur that this sounds like homework. Though we are here to help one another, you should have at least attempted something prior to asking the community for help. I recommend you write out a solution algorithm outlining how you would solve this problem on your own.

Comment: @Tass & j08691: Its not a homework dude... Its just a random problem from a list to which I got no idea to start

Comment: Then I do apologize, but it is common for users to post homework questions. Have you sketched out how you would complete this problem if you didn't have a computer? That's what I mean by "solution algorithm."

Comment: There's absolutely no need to apologize... and with the help of @tymeJV, I was able to figure out the solution. P.S. I do have a computer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ejDQt/3/

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    makeChange($("#amt").val());
});

function makeChange(total) {
    var amtArray = [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1];

    $("span").each(function(i) {
            //Set the span
            $(this).text(parseInt(total / amtArray[i]));
            //Get the new total
            total = total % amtArray[i];
    });
}
```

The function just goes down the line of possible bills and tries to make change. This won't work with any decimals, just nicely rounded numbers.

HTML to make more sense of above code:

```
<input type="text" id="amt"/><input type="button" value="change" id="btn"/>

<br/>

Hundreds: <span></span><br/>
Fifties: <span></span><br/>
Twenties: <span></span><br/>
Tens: <span></span><br/>
Fives: <span></span><br/>
Twos: <span></span><br/>
Ones: <span></span><br/>
```

Edit: Updated Fiddle above per Jeff B's comment.

Comment: Appending text to the span makes it really hard to change the value on a subsequent calculation.  Why not make the span not contain the text?  `Hundreds: <span></span>`  Then you can easily replace the value without having to do string manipulation.

Comment: Well...this is a much better idea, let me mod this real quick.

Comment: And now you want to get rid of the `if(total/amtArray[i] !=0)` or else on subsequent calculations you may not overwrite previous values if the new value is `0`.  http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/4YEhZ/

Comment: Explains some of the irrational results I saw earlier. Thanks for cleaning this up

Comment: @tymeJV: How do I use this in a .html file ? Should I place the script within <script> tags?

Comment: Yes, also, it uses jQuery, be sure to include the jQuery lib on your page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head><title>Display the Denomination</title></head>
<body><script>
a=prompt("Enter number"," ");
n=parseInt(a);
h=Math.floor(n/100);
n=n-h*100;
f=Math.floor(n/50);
n=n-f*50;
tw=Math.floor(n/20);
n=n-tw*20;
t=Math.floor(n/10);
n=n-t*10;
fi=Math.floor(n/5);
n=n-fi*5;
two=Math.floor(n/2);
n=n-two*2;
one=Math.floor(n/1);
document.write("Hundreds="+h+"<br>Fifties="+f+"<br>Twenties="+tw+"<br>Tens="+t+"<br>Fives="+fi+"<br>Twos="+two+"<br>Ones="+one);
</script>
</body></html>
```