# Put values in table dynamically in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07YI6.png)

I want to insert into this table remaining amount.
I am able to get reaming amount but i have no idea how to put it into table.

Comment: Provide your code, so it is possible to see what are you doing and what can be done

Comment: I think you are looking for this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363129/writing-a-javascript-to-display-the-denomination-of-the-amount-deposited

Comment: Sample JSFiddle in the answer.. http://jsfiddle.net/ejDQt/3/